# jQuery dropdown issue (cant keep the submenu visible)

Tags: jquery, menu, hover, drop-down-menu

I am building a small dropdown menu with jQuery, but i am have a small issue.
When I enter the menu it drops down, but when i want to go to the dropdown part with my mouse it will go back up(hide). 
This is because the markup of the menu is a little bit different than most jQuery dropdown menus(i think).

The menu should be visible if a user hovers the a tag, but because the div tag isn't a child of the a tag so it will fadeout if a user leave the a tag. Is there a way to fix this? I cant find any thing about this on the web.

Menu markup

```
     <ul>
        <li>
            <span>Some text</span>
            <a href="#"><img src="icon.png"/></a>
            <div>here comes the dropdown list</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Some text</span>
            <a href="#"><img src="icon.png"/></a>
            <div>here comes the dropdown list</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Some text</span>
            <a href="#"><img src="icon.png"/></a>
            <div>here comes the dropdown list</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

jQuery code markup

```
    $('a').hover(function(){                     

        $(this).next('div').fadeIn(200);

    },function(){

        $(this).next('div').fadeOut(200);

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fade out shouldn't be bound to the anchor but to the div.

You can begin to show the div when anchor is hovered:

```
$('a').on("mouseenter", function() {
  $(this).next('div').fadeIn(200);
});
```

Then hide the div when mouse leaves it:

```
$('div').on("mouseleave", function() {
  $(this).fadeOut(200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your hover event is targeting the link element, when you hover out of the link you hide the menu item.

To prevent this behaviour, simply target the parent element instead, in this case the

:

```
$('li').hover(function(){

    $(this).children('div').fadeIn(200);

},function(){

    $(this).children('div').fadeOut(200);

});
```

Comment: I know but as i mention the menu has to be triggerd by the a tag, and not with a li tag, as the menu has a kind of a split layout.